# How to enable specific VScode notification？

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

When I use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to format a python file, VScode gives me a notification at bottom-right corner:

> ##### Formatter autopep8 is not installed? Install?
>
> `Yes`|`Use black`|`Use yapf`|`Do not disturb`

I am not sure if the last choice is `Do not disturb` or some other things.

However I clicked it by accident. Now this notification will not be shown no matter what I do.

How can I make it back?

Comment: Have you tried to open the settings.json and checked if there is a marker for the "do not disturb" there? Open Visual Studio Code.
Press Ctrl + Shift + P (on Mac Cmd + Shift + P) and type "Open Settings( JSON)" and click on it.

Comment: look in `settings,json` (Global or Workspace) and search for `python` and remove the settings that look related to formatting

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You could use code `"pip show autopep8"` to check whether autopep8 has been installed because you're not sure which option you clicked.

**1. You have chosen the first three options**

If you have installed the autopep8 and you are sure that you want to see this notification again, you can "pip uninstall autopep8" and repeat the previous formatting operation.

Black and yapf do the same.

**2.You have chosen the last one**

After repeated tests and queries, when you select "do not disturb" (for which I uninstall autopep8), there is no new line in setting.json. I queried various keywords in setting and didn't find the content related to this reminder. The setting of this report should exist in the database file of vscode.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Change the `"FORMATTER_NOT_INSTALLED_KEY":true` into "false".

**So, the best way to solve this question is to download autopep8 by using "pip install autopep8"**